# How to Use auto layout to layout three item horizontal equal

Tags: ios, autolayout

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have a static table view cell which contains three UIImageViews.

I'd like the spacing between the items to be double the spacing between the screen edge and the outer items.

The spacing should dynamically change depending on screen width (the item size is static).

How can I achieve this using auto layout?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: is it static or it may change dynamically?

Comment: space dynamically change depend on screen width but the item size is static

Comment: Add 6 UIView in between the three UIImageView, set constraint that all items with same width, and linking the leading and trailing space to zero. Also set all 9 items align vertically center. To maintain the icon's graphics, you may also constraint the aspect ratio of the three UIImageView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create three holder views, one for each item, they should be placed side wise with `width constraint = superview.width / 3 + 0`. Then in those three holder views you add your items and set their `centerY/centerX` to `centerY/centerX` of holder view

In that way they would have exactly same layout which you want.

[image]

Comment: how can i set holder views width constraint = superview.width/3 + 0 in Storyboard? Thanks@Usama

Comment: Image is attached showing the respective constraint, you will have to add aspect ratio constraint between to HolderView and SuperView to get the attached screenshot screen, then modify as it is shown in pic

Comment: if you are still having issue, upload a test project somewhere i will edit it and attach the solution with this answer.

Comment: Thanks for hot help.I get what I want in any size device :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the restriction display as per my comment above. You can specify the restrictions within the XIB editor.

Add 6 UIView in between the three UIImageView, set constraint that

- all 9 items with same width
- and linking the leading and trailing space to zero
- all 9 items align vertically center
- set the aspect ratio of the three UIImageView.

In the screen snapshot below I have added bg colour for those UIWebView to show their existences.

[image: A prototype cell]

Comment: Why add extra views when you can do it without any of them?

Comment: Auto layout without program code and size of UIImage also resizes according to the screen size. Now I learn how to use the multiplier from the above answer. but I don't know if the UIImage will becomes larger on 6+ screen and iPad or not.